# Angular2 CLI not creating route

Tags: angular, typescript1.8

I am using angular2-cli beta1

When I do the following

```
ng generate route new-patient
```

The prompt gives the following

```
C:\workspace\epimss\angular2\ts\epimss\src\app]ng generate route new-patient
installing route
installing component
  create src\app\+new-patient\new-patient.component.css
  create src\app\+new-patient\new-patient.component.html
  create src\app\+new-patient\new-patient.component.spec.ts
  create src\app\+new-patient\new-patient.component.ts
  create src\app\+new-patient\index.ts
  create src\app\+new-patient\shared\index.ts
No component annotation was found...
```

No other injection occurs in any other file, including the AppComponent.

I am trying to follow the ng-conf-2016 video found at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHZe6gGI5RY

The application runs normally otherwise and I have the following route in one of my components:

```
<a [routerLink] = "['new-patient']">New Patient</a>
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks